# Usar classes remotamente no php

Tags: php

Bom dia!

Estou tentando criar um sistema de verificação de "serial" com php.
Funcionaria mais ou menos assim.
Em um servidor X ele vai armazenar as views do servidor Y;
No servidor Y eu teria apenas um molde em html onde seria exibido essas views.

Mas para isso o Servidor X precisa comparar uma chave, como se fosse um serial de verificação, assim como em alguns programas desktop que quando você o compra recebe uma chave de registro.
Essa chave ficaria armazenada no servidor Y e seria fixa, o Servidor X vai armazenar no seu próprio banco de dados, txt ou onde for possível. varias dessas chaves.

Peço desculpas se não fui claro, mas estou desde as 6 da manha de ontem tentando e até agora não consegui nada viável.
Um detalhe, o servidor Y não pode saber como é feito o armazenamento dessas informações, ele só precisa confirmar se as chaves batem e receber as views do servidor X.

```
          <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Teste</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/form.css">
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img id="logo-top" src="img/logo.png" alt="">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <?php
            include_once 'http://servidor.com.br/end/ctl/Version.class.php';
            ?>
        </div>
        <footer>
        </footer>
    </body>

    </html>
        <?php
class Version {
    private $client;
    private $server = array("!01@1-1#20-15$0-3%14",
                            "!01@1-1#20-15$0-3%15");

    public function checarVersao($link){
        $ponteiro = fopen($link, "r");

        while(!feof($ponteiro)) {
            $linha = fgets($ponteiro, 4096);
            $this->client = $linha;

            if(in_array($linha, $this->server)) {
                switch($linha) {
                    case "!01@1-1#20-15$0-3%14":
                        include_once '../viw/index.php';
                        break;
                    case "!01@1-1#20-15$0-3%15":
                        include_once '../viw/erro404.php';
                        break;
                }
            } else {
                echo '<script>alert("Erro no serial");</script>';
                echo '<div id="serial-incorreto">serial incorreto! verifique o serial fornecido e tente novamente.</div>';
            }
        }
        fclose($ponteiro);
    }
}
$version = new Version();
$version->checarVersao('servidor.com.br/end/serial.txt');

?>
```

Comment: Isso está parecendo mais coisa de javascript do que de PHP, hein! Tome cuidado com essa operação

Comment: O problema é a visibilidade do código entre os dois servidores.
Não consegui definir exatamente no que isso se encaixa, uma porque o php não compila os arquivos e é server-side, andei lendo sobre web services mas não entendi muito bem, além de me parecer inútil pra esse caso.

Comment: Aparentemente o que você quer é impedir cópia ou uso indevido de seu código. Se for realmente isso, já adianto que é inútil tentar essas coisas em PHP. Qualquer programador com um pouquinho só de experiência quebra essa barreira sem dificuldade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bem, talvez o que você queira fazer seja algo assim:

Servidor A

```
$chave = 'XXXYZ';
```

SERVIDOR B

```
$chave = 'XXXYZ';
```

SERVIDOR B será o servidor que retornará a informação do arquivo externo requisitado. Porém toda essa requisição terá que passar pelo script principal, para não ter problemas de acessos diretos por alheios.

## SERVIDOR B

```
#request.php

$arquivo = $_GET['nome_arquivo'];

$chaveCliente = $_GET['chave'];

if ($chave === $chaveCliente) {
     include DIRETORIO_PADRAO . $arquivo . '.php';
}
```

SERVIDOR A:

```
 $opts = array(
      'http'=>array(
         'method'=> 'GET',
         'content' => http_build_query([
                   'chave' => $chave,
                    'nome_arquivo' => 'view_cadastro'
                  ])

       )
 );


 $dados_view = file_get_contents('http://www.servidor-b.com/request.php', false, $opts);
```

Não recomendo de forma alguma essa operação, mas dentro que você pediu, tentei fazer da maneira mais segura possível.

Comment: Eu editei a pergunta pra postar o que eu consegui fazer, ele realmente funcionou, mas isso me gerou  problemas.
O principal é que ambos os servidores precisam estar com o allow_url_include ativadas, e em um deles não tenho acesso ao php.ini
Sem contar que preciso que ele se auto inclua, e não seja preciso passar parâmetros pelo get

Comment: Meu amigo, nesse caso, você pode fazer como eu fiz, porém usando `curl`.

Comment: Pelo que vi a principio o curl pode resolver mesmo o problema, grato pela suas respostas!